# Modify updated_at attribute through db trigger in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if there is anything wrong about updating the updated_at attribute of a record through a db trigger in terms of fragment caching (i.e. the partials dont get re-cached / the old cache keys do not disappear from memory).

*additional info* I'm using a trigger due to using the upsert gem which does not modify the updated_at attribute unless explicitly told to do so ( which I do not want to do ); also, due to the same gem I cannot use an active::record after_save or before_save on the model.

Please let me know if there any other information I should provide to add some clarity to my question.

Comment: There isn't anything particularly wrong but I would urge you to consider doing it in code so there aren't surprising side-effects to other developers that do not know about the trigger. If you use Rails 6 `upsert_all` you can pass `returning: :id` to get the IDs back and then do `Model.where(id: ids).update(updated_at: Time.current)`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't nothing wrong, but if you need to do so you can simply use `record.touch` in a method so your code will be more clean and app will be more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to achive that is to use `on_duplicate` attribute of the Rails `upsert_all` method (without any gems). Check the [documentation](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-upsert_all), pseudo code example:

```
YourModel.upsert_all(
  array_of_data,
  unique_by: %i[field_1 field_2],
  on_duplicate: Arel.sql('updated_at = current_timestamp')
)
```

If you have other fields to update, don't forget to add them into Arel.sql:

```
on_duplicate: Arel.sql('updated_at = current_timestamp, field_to_update = excluded.field_to_update')
```